# Cannot manipulate nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am using the following code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
calc,%
fadings,%
shadings%
}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}%MM structure
%PCB
\draw[rounded corners, color=Darkgreen, fill=green, path fading=south] (0,0) rectangle     (11,0.6);
\draw node at (11.4,0.1) {\footnotesize \textcolor{Darkgreen}{\eng{PCB}}};%name it

%Read-Out Strips
\draw[color=orange, fill=orange] (1,0.6) rectangle (2,1);
\draw[color=orange, fill=orange] (3,0.6) rectangle (4,1);
\draw[color=orange, fill=orange] (5,0.6) rectangle (6,1);
\draw[color=orange, fill=orange] (7,0.6) rectangle (8,1);
\draw[color=orange, fill=orange] (9,0.6) rectangle (10,1);
\draw node at (11.4,0.8) {\footnotesize \textcolor{orange}{\eng{Strips}}};%name it

\draw node[ground] at (1.5,-1) {};
\draw node at (1.5,-1) {} to [R] (1.5,0);%<--------This is what I want to do
%\draw node[ground] to [R] (1.5,-1);
%\draw node[R] at (1.5,0) {};

%Micro-Mesh
\draw[very thick, color=gray, dashed] (0,3) -- (11,3);
\draw node at (11.4,3) {\footnotesize \textcolor{gray}{\eng{Mesh}}};%name it
\draw (0,3.5) -- (0,2.5) -- (-0.5,3) -- (0,3.5);
\draw node at (-1,3) {\footnotesize \eng{-HV}};%name it
\draw node at (-2,1.8) {\footnotesize \eng{Amplification}};
\draw node at (-2,1.4) {\footnotesize \eng{Gap}};

%Drift
\draw[very thick, color=gray] (0,6) -- (11,6);
\draw node at (11.4,6) {\footnotesize \textcolor{gray}{\eng{Drift}}};%name it
\draw (0,6.5) -- (0,5.5) -- (-0.5,6) -- (0,6.5);
\draw node at (-1,6) {\footnotesize \eng{-HV}};%name it
\draw node at (-2,4.8) {\footnotesize \eng{Drift}};
\draw node at (-2,4.4) {\footnotesize \eng{Region}};

%Particle's track
\draw[color=red,->] (0.2,7) -- (11.4,-1);
\draw node at (2.5,6.5) {\footnotesize \textcolor{red}{\eng{Particle's Track}}};%name     it

%electron
\draw (3,5) --(3.2,3);
\draw node at (1.5,4) {\eng{Primary's}};
\draw node at (1.6,3.6) {\eng{track}};

%avalanche
\draw[very thick, red, rotate=0, fill=red] (3.15,3) .. controls (2.15,0.4) and     (4.25,0.4) .. (3.25,3);
\draw[color=red] node at (1.8,1.5) {\eng{Avalanche}};

\end{circuitikz}
\caption{}%
\label{}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

All I am trying to do is place a resistor and a gound below the first orange rectangle. While ground is placed as it should be, the resistor doesn't. I don;t know how to figure this out...Any suggestions will be welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `\draw` for putting nodes on the fly but then giving explicit coordinates to the nodes which is overriding the previous mechanism.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw[rounded corners, fill=green, path fading=south] (0,0) rectangle     (11,0.6);
\draw node at (11.4,0.1) {\footnotesize \textcolor{green}{PCB}};%name it
\draw[color=orange, fill=orange] (1,0.6) rectangle (2,1);
\draw[color=orange, fill=orange] (3,0.6) rectangle (4,1);
\draw[color=orange, fill=orange] (5,0.6) rectangle (6,1);
\draw[color=orange, fill=orange] (7,0.6) rectangle (8,1);
\draw[color=orange, fill=orange] (9,0.6) rectangle (10,1);
\draw node at (11.4,0.8) {\footnotesize \textcolor{orange}{Strips}};%name it

\draw (0.5,0) to[R] (2.5,0) --++(0.2,0) node[ground] {};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!It is working!!! Actually I changed your code into `\draw (1.5,0.6) -- (1.5,0.5) to[R] (1.5,-0.5) --(1.5,-1) node[ground] {};` which is working in my case if I add `\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.6cm}` before `circuittikz` enviroment. Thank's once again!!!